# Jetpack Compose animateContentSize Is Laggy When There Is An Image With ContentScale Crop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that animates the content size on scroll. This composable contains one Surface that contains Image and Column

```
@Composable
fun TopCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, canScrollUp: Boolean = false) {
    val animateHeigh by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (canScrollUp) 110.dp else 180.dp)
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
            .height(animateHeigh)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = spring(
                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy,
                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium
                )
            ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.cardbackground),
            contentDescription = "card background",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Column(modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Ono Cash")
            Text(text = "Total Saldo", modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp))
            Text(text = "Rp 0", modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            ) {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.AddCircle, contentDescription = "Top Up")
                    Text(text = "Top Up")
                }
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.FileUpload, contentDescription = "Transfer")
                    Text(text = "Transfer")
                }
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Menu, contentDescription = "Transfer")
                    Text(text = "Transfer")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The animation becomes laggy when I set contentScale property of Image composable to Crop as you can see on [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xIB2PFZQZD5VGLU_Cc2JaahFi-QIhlA/view)

But, when I remove the contentScale property, the animation works well. [The video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12pi-CB4FoHt5T26dyXYk5JzSHE2HGW9O/view)

How do I solve this issue?

I've tried to set animateContentSize() function on the Image composable. But it didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the image was to big that causes the laggy